# Hibernate ORDER BY ASC|DESC não funciona passando por parametro

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Bom, estou com um problema na ordenação de uma consulta, onde estou passando o nome do campo juntamente com **ASC** ou **DESC** como parametro para a query, porem o hibernate não está se achando, retornando a consulta sem a ordenação. Alguem teria uma solução para esse problema?

Segue o codigo:

```
String filtro = "nome DESC"; //ou "nome ASC"

Query query = manager
.createQuery("select t from ProdutosVO as t "+
"where t.codigoEmpresa = :paramCodigo ORDER BY :paramFiltro");
query.setParameter("paramCodigo", codigoEmpresa);
query.setParameter("paramFiltro", filtro);
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, resolvi o meu problema da seguinte forma, concatenando o filtro diretamente na query:

```
String filtro = "nome DESC"; //ou "nome ASC"

Query query = manager
.createQuery("select t from ProdutosVO as t "+
"where t.codigoEmpresa = :paramCodigo ORDER BY "+filtro);
query.setParameter("paramCodigo", codigoEmpresa);
```

Porem, fica a duvida do por que o hibernate não aceita o order by como parâmetro.

Answer (score 4):

Não é possivel usar parametros para o Order By nessa caso você deve criar uma "criteria" exemplo:

```
Criteria c = manager.createCriteria(Classe.class);
c.createAlias("paramFiltro", "campo");
c.addOrder(Order.asc("paramFiltro.value"));
return c.list();
```